# Postgres JDBC Numbered Parameters

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I have a table in a Postgres 9.3 database with a json column like this:

```
CREATE mytable (
  mycolumn json
)
```

I would like to execute queries from a Java application that look like this:

```
SELECT
  mycolumn->>'somefield',
  count(*)
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY
  mycolumn->>'somefield'
```

When I try to use a PreparedStatement like this:

```
SELECT
  mycolumn->>?,
  count(*)
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY
  mycolumn->>?
```

I get the following error:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: column "mytable.mycolumn" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

It makes sense that this happens because Postgres cannot guarantee that the two positional parameters are the same.

Using psql, I can prepare a statement like this:

```
PREPARE mystatement AS
  SELECT
    mycolumn->>$1,
    count(*)
  FROM
    mytable
  GROUP BY
    mycolumn->>$1
```

Is it possible to do this with JDBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible. JDBC only has positional parameters, and therefor the PostgreSQL driver will render it as:

```sql
PREPARE mystatement AS
  SELECT
    mycolumn->>$1,
    count(*)
  FROM
    mytable
  GROUP BY
    mycolumn->>$2
```

And as the value of `$1` is not necessarily the same as `$2`, the parser of PostgreSQL will reject it as you are potentially not grouping on the same column.

The solution might be to do:

```
SELECT a.aColumnLabel, count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT mycolumn->>? as aColumnLabel
    FROM mytable
) a
GROUP BY a.aColumnLabel
```

Answer (score 0):

[CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) can make Mark's solution a bit more readable by having all parameters in the first line (like a poor man's function definition) and accessing them by name in the query itself:

```sql
WITH vars AS (SELECT ? aColumnLabel)
SELECT
  mycolumn->>vars.aColumnLabel,
  count(*)
FROM
  mytable, vars
GROUP BY
  mycolumn->>vars.aColumnLabel
```